# Can pak choi be re-grown?

Tags: vegetables, harvesting

I know that [pak choi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_cabbage) can be grown as a "cut and keep" plant, but can I regrow it from the base of the plant, as [can be done with celery](http://www.17apart.com/2012/02/growing-celery-indoors-never-buy-celery.html)?

If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible: Pak Choy is a plant containing much water, and it will dry out faster than roots and leaves can start to grow.

Maybe it is possible to harvest only the outer leaves, while letting the central small ones at the plant, leaving the plant in the soil. We are doing this with chard (*Beta vulgaris* subsp. *vulgaris*).